# TD style font-weight not applying bold formatting

Tags: html, css

Am I being really really silly here?

I've tested this line completely on it's own and the text is NOT bold?

```
<td style="font-weight:bold">example</td>
```

Surely this should work? I've tested this on my server and on two HTML emulators. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Is you `<td>` enclosed by `<table>` tag

Comment: Many browsers handle errors like this by removing the tags and leaving only the content. As you can see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ygac4z6c/) by inspecting the text "example". The tags are gone, only the text remains.

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal Actually, it should be enclosed by a `<tr>`, and _then_ by a `<table>` tag.

Comment: Why would you have and test a Table Data (TD) cell all by itself without a Table and a Table Row (TR)? All by itself it is an invalid html.

Comment: @jmoerdyk I know that Even if `tr` is not there `font-weight` will work

Comment: Thanks guys, me being an amateur! Lesson learnt!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<td>` tag can be used only inside `<table>` and strictly wrapped with `<tr>` tag as:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight: bold">text here</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-TD

Comment: OMG thank you! I had literally no idea you had to have it wrapped in a table!

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that you are using the proper enclosing table tags as well:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold">bold example</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>non-bold</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2h8qp2qd/

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline css on this below code. If not working you can try the option 2.

```
<td style="font-weight:bold">example</td>
```

This is the easiest way.

```
<td><b>example</b></td>
```

Answer (score -1):

`<td>` is only used inside a `<table>`.

Use: `font-weight: bold;`

```css
td.bolded{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Not Bolded</td>
      <td class="bolded">Bolded</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The keyword `bold` actually has a boldness of 700, not 600. [Source](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/font-weight).